# Is there any tool in Flutter that allows you to perform any function only on the selected day, month, year and time?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an application in Flutter for online queries and right now I'm lost as to how to show the user, for example, a message based on the exact time he previously chose. The user can already choose the day, month, year and time, and after he selects them, I can store them as Strings, but I don't know of any tool that can perform some function at that exact moment. What I want to do is that after entering the information of the day and time of the consultation, a notification appears to the user asking him if he wants to join the video call, but only at the time he chose.

I tried to calculate the difference between the chosen date and the current moment, and based on that duration I used the Timer to execute some task after the elapsed time. But I was also in doubt if this function would be executed even if the user had not opened the application, so I don't know if it would really work or not. Previously I also researched dependencies that could help, I found for example the sf_calendar, but from what I observed it only has a system to choose the date and save and display this data on the screen, but it does not allow performing some function on that date.